# Can I use boto to add an "ok_action" to an existing cloudwatch alarm without creating a new alarm?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, boto, amazon-cloudwatch

I have 700 cloudwatch alarms that my users created without actions in the "OKActions", which means they don't self resolve.

These are already in prod so i am hesitant to delete\move\etc.

In the AWS console I can simply add a new action.
However I cannot find such an action in the [docs for boto](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client):

```
can_paginate()
delete_alarms()
delete_dashboards()
describe_alarm_history()
describe_alarms()
describe_alarms_for_metric()
disable_alarm_actions()
enable_alarm_actions()
generate_presigned_url()
get_dashboard()
get_metric_data()
get_metric_statistics()
get_metric_widget_image()
get_paginator()
get_waiter()
list_dashboards()
list_metrics()
put_dashboard()
put_metric_alarm()
put_metric_data()
set_alarm_state()
```

Can I use boto to add an "ok_action" to an existing cloudwatch alarm without creating a new alarm ?

AWS cli ?
Some other aws automation ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `put_metric_alarm` with Boto3.  I'll add some example code when I have a few minutes, below is a CLI reference.

**NOTE!!**

> When you update an existing alarm, its state is left unchanged, but the update completely overwrites the previous configuration of the alarm.

I verified this is the same action when using the command line tools.

**Before:**

```
    {
        "AlarmName": "CPU_High",
        "AlarmArn": "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-east-1:<redacted>:alarm:CPU_High",
        "AlarmDescription": "Check for High CPU usage",
        "AlarmConfigurationUpdatedTimestamp": "2019-02-04T17:53:54.236Z",
        "ActionsEnabled": true,
        "OKActions": [],
        "AlarmActions": [
            "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:<redacted>:<redacted>"
        ],
    <deleted non-pertinent info>
    }
```

**CLI Command:**

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm --alarm-name "CPU_High" --metric-name "CPUUtilization" --period 300 --ok-actions "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:<redacted>:<redacted>" --evaluation-periods 1 --threshold 99.0 --comparison-operator "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold" --namespace "AWS/EC2" --statistic "Average"
```

**After:**

```
{
        "AlarmName": "CPU_High",
        "AlarmArn": "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-east-1:<redacted>:alarm:CPU_High",
        "AlarmConfigurationUpdatedTimestamp": "2019-02-04T18:05:02.592Z",
        "ActionsEnabled": true,
        "OKActions": [
            "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:<redacted>:<redacted>"
        ],
        "AlarmActions": [],
    <deleted non-pertinent info>

    }
```

**From AWS Support**

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for contacting AWS Premium Support. My name is Sonal and I will be assisting you with the case.
>
> I understand that you would like to add OK Action to the existing alarms without modifying anything else in the alarm configuration. Since you need to add this action to all your alarms, so you are looking for a way to do this custom script.
>
> "PutMetricAlarm" is the only API used for both Creating and Updating an alarm. Please note that when you update an existing alarm using "PutMetricAlarm" API, the update completely overwrites the previous configuration of the alarm. This means that you have to specify all the parameters of the existing alarm along with the parameters you want to modify.
>
> So in order to modify the existing alarms, your custom script would need to do the following: -->Get a list of all the alarms to be updated. You can use "DescribeAlarms" API[1](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html) -->You can parse the list of alarms, extract the required parameters --> Use the above parameters to make a "PutMetricAlarm" API[2] call along with the OKActions parameter.
>
> Please note that providing with actual code for deploying these solutions for your specific environment would be out of scope of AWS Support but, of course, we will be able to guide you during the process if you face any issues.

**Reference:**

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html

Comment: but this still means dealing with the entire config. I can't just add one ok action, it is TECHNICALLY not creating a new alarm, but it does not have me touch only one thing without changing anything else.

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger.  You asked if it could be done, the answer is yes.  The caveat is you need to include your current config when you add it.

Comment: please alter the answer to include my comments and i will upvote it and confirm it got the answer

Answer (score 0):

Amazon's Answer:

tl;dr: There isn't a good way to do this.

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for contacting AWS Premium Support. My name is Sonal and I
>   will be assisting you with the case.
>
> I understand that you would like to add OK Action to the existing
>   alarms without modifying anything else in the alarm configuration.
>   Since you need to add this action to all your alarms, so you are
>   looking for a way to do this custom script.
>
> "PutMetricAlarm" is the only API used for both Creating and Updating
>   an alarm. Please note that when you update an existing alarm using
>   "PutMetricAlarm" API, the update completely overwrites the previous
>   configuration of the alarm. This means that you have to specify all
>   the parameters of the existing alarm along with the parameters you
>   want to modify.
>
> So in order to modify the existing alarms, your custom script would
>   need to do the following:
>   -->Get a list of all the alarms to be updated. You can use "DescribeAlarms" API[1] 
>   -->You can parse the list of alarms, extract the required parameters 
>   --> Use the above parameters to make a "PutMetricAlarm" API[2] call along with the OKActions parameter.
>
> Please note that providing with actual code for deploying these
>   solutions for your specific environment would be out of scope of AWS
>   Support but, of course, we will be able to guide you during the
>   process if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

So I had to do something similar with the 'AlarmActions' parameter in boto3.   I will change up my code for a fictional 'OKActions' parameter.  The function below isn't *exactly* what I wrote, but I'm simplifying it for clarity's sake.

```py
def change_alarm_ok_action(cloudwatch_client, alarm):
    new_ok_action = 'arn:aws-us-east-1:blah:blah:new_ok_action'
    
    new_alarm_dict = alarm
    new_alarm_dict['OKActions'] = [new_ok_action]
    #when I ran the code, it gave me an error that a bunch of parameters I had in my alarm 
    #were not allowed, 
    #so I went down the list of the parameters it told me to remove and popped them.
    #you may need to do the same.
    new_alarm_dict.pop('AlarmArn', None)
    new_alarm_dict.pop('StateValue', None)
    new_alarm_dict.pop('StateReason', None)
    new_alarm_dict.pop('StateReasonData', None)
    new_alarm_dict.pop('StateUpdatedTimestamp', None)
    new_alarm_dict.pop('AlarmConfigurationUpdatedTimestamp', None)
    #here is where I then used the put_metric_alarm() command
    #because the command only takes kwargs, I had to change my dict into kwargs
    #luckily python has an easy way to do this
    cloudwatch_client.put_metric_alarm(**new_alarm_dict)
```

if you go back and print your alarm you'll get the new OKAction.

```
{'ActionsEnabled': True,
 'AlarmActions': ['arn:us-east-1:blah:blah'],
 'AlarmDescription': 'CPU_Utilization_instance:blah',
 'AlarmName': 'CPU_Utilization_instance:blah',
 'ComparisonOperator': 'GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold',
 'DatapointsToAlarm': 3,
 'Dimensions': [{'Name': 'InstanceId', 'Value': 'blah'}],
 'EvaluationPeriods': 3,
 'InsufficientDataActions': [],
 'MetricName': 'CPUUtilization',
 'Namespace': 'AWS/EC2',
 'OKActions': ['arn:aws-us-east-1:blah:blah:new_ok_action'],
 'Period': 300,
 'Statistic': 'Average',
 'Threshold': 80.0,
 'TreatMissingData': 'missing'}
```

Source: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.put_metric_alarm